# Find a basis of the solution space of this system

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis of the solution space of this system:

$2x_1 + 4x_2 - 2x_4 + 2x_5 = 0$

$2x_1+8x_2+2x_3+6x_5=0$

$4x_1+12x_2+2x_3-2x_4+8x_5=0$

I may have this one correct but I was doubtful about a few things so please just go through my working and tell me what you think.

$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 0 & {-2} & 2 & :{0} \\ 2 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 6 & :{0} \\ 4 & 12 & 2 & {-2} & 8 & :{0} \end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2}R_1 \to \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & {-1} & 1 & :{0} \\ 2 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 6 & :{0} \\ 4 & 12 & 2 & {-2} & 8 & :{0} \end{bmatrix} R_2-2R_1, R_3-4R_1 \to \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & {-1} & 1 & :{0} \\ 0 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 & :{0} \\ 0 & 4 & 2 & {2} & 4 & :{0} \end{bmatrix} R_3-R_2 \to \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & {-1} & 1 & :{0} \\ 0 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 & :{0} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & :{0} \end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2}R2 \to \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & {-1} & 1 & :{0} \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & :{0} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & :{0} \end{bmatrix} R_1-R_2 \to \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & {-1} & {-2} & {-1} & :{0} \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & :{0} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & :{0} \end{bmatrix}$

$x_1 = x_3+2x_4+x_5$

$2x_2 = -x_3-x_4-2x_5$

$x_2 = -\frac{1}{2}x_3 -\frac{1}{2}x_4-x_5$

$(x_3+2x_4+x_5, -\frac{1}{2}x_3-\frac{1}{2}x_4-x_5, x_3, x_4, x_5) = x_1(0,0,0,0,0) + x_2(0,0,0,0,0) + x_3(1,-\frac{1}{2}, 1,0,0) +x_4(2,-\frac{1}{2},0,1,0) +x_5(1,-1,0,0,1) = x_3 {\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ {-\frac{1}{2}} \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}} X_4 {\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ {-\frac{1}{2}} \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}} + x_5 {\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ {-1} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}}$

Comment: I'm not going to check your working but the gist is as follows, you go as far as you can with RREF, if the solution has dimension 0 - GREAT! If it has 1 free variable, dimension 1 and so forth. A basis is any set of vectors - with the same number of vectors as the dimension of the solution space - that span the solution space.

Comment: All the coefficients in the original system are even. For working by hand, it might be advisable to start by dividing 'em all by 2, to make for smaller numbers.

Comment: I checked in sage the following $\text{sage:B=matrix([[2,4,0,-2,2],[2,8,2,0,6],[4,12,2,-2,8]])};\text{B.echelon_form()};$ $\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
2 & 0 & -2 & -4 & -2 \\
0 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ So the echelon form you got is the same with sage.